# Get column from 2D list in Python

Tags: python

I have a 2D list and like to get individual column from the list.

```
          X=[]
          for line in lines:
             c,xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = line.split(' ')
             xmin_ = float(xmin)
             ymin_ = float(ymin)
             xmax_ = float(xmax)
             ymax_ = float(ymax)
             area_ = (xmax_ - xmin_)*(ymax_ - ymin_)
             X.append(xmax_-xmin_, ymax_-ymin_, area_)
```

If I print column values, I have error as

```
>>>X[:,1]

*** TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

But why the following example works

```
>>> a = arange(20).reshape(4,5)

>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

>>> a[:, 1]
array([ 1,  6, 11, 16])
```

What is the difference?

Comment: List and np.array is not the same ...

Comment: Aside: `a = arange(20).reshape(4,5)` makes me worry that you've done something like `from numpy import *`, or are working in an environment that does it automatically.  That's a bad idea, not just because it can lead to confusion about what's Python and what's numpy (as happened here), but because it can lead to mysterious bugs because of builtins being overridden.  Just get used to `import numpy as np`, it'll save you a lot of headaches down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the list to numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
x=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
x[:,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
xa = np.array(x)
xa
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
xa[:,1]
array([2, 5])
```